# Generate Swashbuckle implementation notes in aspnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate swagger documentation. Unfortunately I can't find how to add the implementation notes, as per attached pictures.

[This is a sample picture of swagger generated documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpJkm.jpg)

Bellow is excerpt from my code to generate some tags.

```
/// <summary>
    /// User login for given application
    /// </summary>
    /// <description>
    /// Test description
    /// </description>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    /// 
    ///     POST /login
    ///     {
    ///         "email": "jon@nighwatch.com",
    ///         "password": "jonLov3sDaenarys"
    ///         "productId": "5e7en-k1ngd0m5"
    ///     }
    ///     
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="model">Login model</param>
    /// <returns>JWT Token</returns>
    /// <response code="200">Returns the newly created auth response, containing token with user information</response>
    /// <response code="400">If the request is invalid or productId doesn't exist</response>
    /// <response code="403">If the account is locked out or role is inactive</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AuthResponseModel), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(403)]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: It has been 2 years, but do you remember your solution? I have the same problem now but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Marijke in the meantime this project was migrated. But if you can provide a gist with a sample, we could try to take a look and see what's the issue.

Comment: I found the solution for me, I only used description because that is what you see in the swagger json, but I had to use <remarks>. Remarks will be converted to description in the json and that will convert to Implementation Notes in the swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the XML documentation file.

**Project Properties** > **Build** > **Output** => Check `XML Documentation file`. Example: `bin\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.xml`

In `ConfigureServices`, where you do `services.AddSwaggerGen(...)`, include the generated file:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyProject.xml");
                options.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
            });
```

If these two things are in place, the xml comments should be included in the documentation.

Comment: I already have the XML comments enabled. See the photo with the swagger I have: https://imgur.com/a/OYYj2W4

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the attributes for swagger?

```
    [SwaggerOperation("Get_Whatever")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(List<string>), "An array of strings.")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, null, "Forbidden")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel model){
```

Comment: Actually [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AuthResponseModel), 200)] does the same thing as   [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(List<string>))]. And if I add the SwaggerOperation I don't see any visible change in the definition

Comment: Oh ok if you see none of the xml comments try the answer of Attila Szasz that should do the trick.